# Having more than one app.component in angular 7

Tags: angular, layout

Being new in `angular`, I want to structure my `layout` into two

1. without `navigation`
2. with `navigation`

Question: Is it possible to have more than 1 `app.component`, if yes how?

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

external.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: in which scenario you are thinking about to use two app.component.ts?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to have pages without navigateion (eg. login, registration) and pages with navigation (eg. dashboard, settings)

Comment: There is one solution to achieve this..let me answer it, but without two app.component.ts

Comment: since <router-outlet></router-outlet> is kept in app.component.html my thought is to have another without navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution of that without using two app.component.ts.
I put the files as I used in my current project.

> app.component.ts

```
 <app-http-loader></app-http-loader>
  <div class="app-root-style">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

> app.router-modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule', canLoad: [HomeGuard] },
  { path: '**', component: FourZeroFourComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> auth-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
      { path: 'dashboard/:uid', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'userinfo', loadChildren: '../user/user.module#UserModule', canLoad: [HomeGuard] },
     }
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

This way you achieve the whole routes

url's will be like this:

> https://localhost:4200/auth/login
>
> https://localhost:4200/home/dashboard/23

See I use **Guard** here to Guard the routes if user not logged in

Comment: Cool! Where will the navigation be add to?

Comment: I mean: <app-nav></app-nav>

Comment: I think you should add this to home.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many router outlets as you want. Simply declare children of your route. Something like that :

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent, children: [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [...] },
    { path: 'profile': component: ProfileComponent, children: [...] },
  ]}
];
```

```html
<!-- Home component template -->
<div>
  <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
  <button (click)="signup()">Sign up</button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- Profile component template -->
<div>
  <button routerLink="dashboard">Dashboard</button>
  <button routerLink="settings">Settings</button>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I want the login to be the first page to load, not home.

Comment: @codegrid Seriously dude ? That's an exemple ... I'm just giving the idea, you can name your components what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have already achieved that. What I want is for the login page to be the landing or entry page.

Comment: Then replace `AppComponent` by `LoginComponent` in the route definition.